# UI through Storyboard or Programmatically?

Tags: ios, user-interface

I'm having trouble getting my text to stay within the width of the screen. I shrunk the text and don't want to make it any smaller (please see below):

[image]

Would it be better, in terms of having an adaptive layout that fits the screen, to use Storyboard instead of doing it programmatically?

This is my existing code for the Left View Controller:

```
import UIKit

protocol LeftViewControllerDelegate {
    func leftUnitSelected(index: WUnit)

    func leftDataChanged(text: String)
}

class LeftViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var leftTextField: UITextField!
    var dataArray: [String] = []
    var delegate: LeftViewControllerDelegate?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.dataArray = ["Litre", "MilliLitre", "Fluid Ounce (US)", "Fluid Ounce (UK)", "Teaspoon (US)", "Teaspoon (UK)", "Tablespoon (US)", "Tablespoon (UK)", "Cup (US)", "Cup (UK)", "Pint (US)", "Pint (UK)", "Quart (US)", "Quart (UK)", "Gallon (US)", "Gallon (UK)"]
        NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI:", name: UITextFieldTextDidChangeNotification, object: self.leftTextField)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    //MARK: UITableView Datasource

    func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.dataArray.count
    }


    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        cell.textLabel!.text = self.dataArray[indexPath.row]
        cell.textLabel!.font = UIFont(name: cell.textLabel!.font.fontName, size:12) // Change the font size as per your requirement
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "20x20_empty-round-radiobutton-choice-ui")
        return cell
    }



    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 32
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "20x20_empty-round-radiobutton-choice-ui")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)!
        cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: "20x20_round-choice-radiobutton-ui")
        if let delegate = delegate {
            delegate.leftUnitSelected(WUnit(rawValue: indexPath.row)!)
        }
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String {
        return "From"
    }

    //MARK: 

    func setText(text: String) {
        self.leftTextField.text = text
    }

    func textFieldTextDidChangeOneCI(notification: NSNotification) {
        let textfield: UITextField = notification.object! as! UITextField
        if Double(textfield.text!) > 0.0 {
            if let delegate = delegate {
                delegate.leftDataChanged(textfield.text!)
            }
        }
    }

    func text() -> String {
        return self.leftTextField.text!
    }
}
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Comment: It's a little unclear (visually) what you have right now and what is the desired result, but as a general rule - try utilize `storyboards` as much as possible - **"less code = less bug"**

Comment: Thanks. My next question is how would I convert the code I currently have to Storyboard layout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A storyboard-based approach handles many of the necessary details to support an adaptive UI.

Apart from that, you could reconsider your design. It's not really a native design for iOS, since iOS doesn't have radio buttons or horizontally compact split tableviews.

You could take a look at existing unit conversion apps to get a feel for how they let users select a unit.

One suggestion is to only ask for one unit (at a time).  Once you know one unit, you could predict the second unit to save the user from having to select that likely choice.

Either way, you should think in terms of trait classes and how your UI would adapt (e.g., modal, popover, split view) for different devices.

As for the UI, you could do this via a picker, a tableview's checkmark accessory view, or a custom control.  Just remember that the more familiar and intuitive the UI appears to a user, the less likely a user will be puzzled by how to use your app.

The less choices you present, the better for the user.  For example, if someone is located in the UK, they likely wouldn't need to convert to a US measure.  If you absolutely need to present all the possible choices, consider separating measures into different sections (by country or system).

Comment: Thanks for these suggestions. I have found a tutorial on doing unit conversion with two side-by-side picker views, much simpler than using code.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have already designed ui in tableview cell & you are setting its height programatically.You can set the lines property of the label from the interface builder in attributes inspector to appropriate lines so that your text will get adjusted accordingly.Also make sure to increase tableview row size from size inspector so that your cell fits accordingly